# Turn string into text file

Tags: php, html, file, textarea

In my website it is possible for the user to enter a rather large amount of text in a html textarea whose information I later handle with PHP. Thing is I need to save the text that the user have input in the textarea, preferably as a txt file in my directory.

I have no idea how to convert the string into a txt file, I have also tried to look for an answer on the internet but I have found nothing. And also just is there any particular data sanitizing functions I should add if I save user input text in my directory?

Thanks

Comment: one line of code using: http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php

Comment: This is way too broad. Saving a text file and most likely unique to the user and/or as a timestamp etc. You will need to be a lot more specific as to the expected end results are to be.

Comment: The expected end results really does not matter as long as the file is in a "readable" shape, it could be a .txt, .doc or .docx, there are no need for anything more than that, really. I do not know if I should say anymore than that?

Comment: did you bother to look at the link I provided?

Comment: You do realize that all contents will be over-written each time the file is saved. You would need some form of uniqueness to save as a new file each time. You can append to a single file, but I doubt that's what you want.

Comment: Thing is everytime I recieve text from users I link that piece together with the php function uniqid(); And I also plan on saving their texts with the filename of their uniqid(); I am pretty sure that that might work?

Answer (score 1):

```
$filename='fish'.uniqid(); //unique filename per Fred's comments

 file_put_contents ($filename , $_POST['YOUR_FORM_FIELD_NAME'] );
```